How to turn off the display from the Raspberry Pi OS
I searched the web on information about turning off the display and controlling its brightness from within the raspberry pi OS, what I gathered is that it works on some displays and not in others.
I'm looking to buy a display between 5 to 7 inch, and I want to be sure that I can control its brightness and be able to turn it off and on from within the Raspberry PI OS. The reason is that I want to have RPI running all day, and I want to save energy and extend the life of the screen by turning it off and sometimes lowering its brightness.
I've checked some Waveshare displays, and what I noticed is that the display can be controlled from within RPI OS, but it seems this is possible only for display with a DSI connector instead of a HDMI one. Another display brand I found has DSI but the display can't be controlled from RPI OS.
Since a lot of these display have poor documentation where they don't state whether they support controlling the display from RPI OS, what should I look for in a display to make sure it does what I want

the title question does not match the rest of the post ... please make corrections

@jsotola what do you suggest the title be? what I want is the ability to turn off the display from RPI OS, so if it's possible in all displays, I want to know how, if not, then I want to know which displays support that functionality

how to choose a display? ... that is what the rest of your post is asking ... or change the post to ask how to turn off display?

For dimming you can adjust the output brightness and for turning off you can simply just stop the output to the display and the display should automatically turn off but I don't know how to turn it back on also most displays also have a setting to auto turn off
They don't like people recommending a single product or service but I would recommend at least a 1080p with 60hz with a rpi 3 and you could do 4k for a rpi 4 and 5 but it may be a little slow
